# Java instantiating a child class in abstract super class

Tags: java, abstract, instantiation, superclass

So what I am trying to make is a Neuroevolution library for some projects I am doing and now I want to make my  code abstract and generic so I can use it in whatever way I need to.

For this I made my DNA class abstract and am now running into issues with my crossover function which returns a new instance of itself with new genes.

```
DNA additiveCrossover(DNA partner) {
    List<T> childGenes = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < genes.size(); i++){
        childGenes.set(i, (addGenes(genes.get(i), (T) partner.getGene(i)));
    }
    return new DNA(childGenes);
}
```

This would previously work as my class wasn't abstract but now I need to find a workaround.

I don't want to make this method abstract as this code should be the same across all my implementations of this class and I can't just make the class not abstract, as it has abstract methods.

Is there any way to instantiate an abstract class so it creates an instance of its child?

My only solution would be a dirty abstract method like this:

```
public class DNA <T> {
    public abstract DNA createFromGenes(List<T> genes);
}

public class DNAImplementation {
    @Override
    public DNA createFromGenes(List<T> genes){
        return new DNAImplementation(genes);
    }
}
```

I really don't like this because it's seemingly unnecessary code and looks awful.

Help would really be appreciated.

Comment: can T be anything or is it a subclass of DNA or ?

Comment: one way would be to implement createFromGenes() in the base class and have it throw, forcing subclasses to inherit. you may be able to extract a method from it that can be put in the base class.

Comment: also, createFromGenes() looks like a factory. these are usually static.

Comment: @RayTayek T is the type of data to be stored in the DNA like integer, char or a neural network (/Neurophs) so it is not important here

Comment: @RayTayek Yes, it would be a Factory, static and abstract don't go together though so it wouldn't work here. Still I want to get rid of that function entirely so I don't have to overwrite methods in the child classes.

Comment: seems like you want a virtual constructor like: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor. the for loop in additive crossover could become static maybe. hard to tell without seeing more code.